# Get column names with corresponding index in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe `df` where

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['10/2/2011', '11/2/2011', '12/2/2011', '13/2/11'],
                    'Event':['Music', 'Poetry', 'Theatre', 'Comedy'],
                    'Cost':[10000, 5000, 15000, 2000],
                    'Name':['Roy', 'Abraham', 'Blythe', 'Sophia'],
                    'Age':['20', '10', '13', '17']})
```

I want to determine the column index with the corresponding name. I tried it with this:

```
>>> list(df.columns)
```

But the solution above only returns the column names without index numbers.

How can I code it so that it would return the **column names and the corresponding index** for that column? Like This:

```
0 Date
1 Event
2 Cost
3 Name
4 Age
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simpliest is add `pd.Series` constructor:

```
pd.Series(list(df.columns))
```

Or convert columns to Series and create default index:

```
df.columns.to_series().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Or:

```
df.columns.to_series(index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

A nice short way to get a dictionary:

```
d = dict(enumerate(df))
```

output: `{0: 'Date', 1: 'Event', 2: 'Cost', 3: 'Name', 4: 'Age'}`

For a Series, `pd.Series(list(df))` is sufficient as iteration occurs directly on the column names

Answer (score 2):

You can use loop like this:

```
myList = list(df.columns)
index = 0

for value in myList:
     print(index, value)
     index += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using `enumerate`, this also can get a numbers in order using `zip`, as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['10/2/2011', '11/2/2011', '12/2/2011', '13/2/11'],
                    'Event':['Music', 'Poetry', 'Theatre', 'Comedy'],
                    'Cost':[10000, 5000, 15000, 2000],
                    'Name':['Roy', 'Abraham', 'Blythe', 'Sophia'],
                    'Age':['20', '10', '13', '17']})

result = list(zip([i for i in range(len(df.columns))], df.columns.values,))

for r in result:
    print(r)

#(0, 'Date')
#(1, 'Event')
#(2, 'Cost')
#(3, 'Name')
#(4, 'Age')
```